# how to test a login page having multiple uesrname and passwords in selenium ide?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

i just want to know which commands are used for data driven testing or Parametrization  having multiple username and password.

Comment: What are you using? IDE or RC?

Comment: If you were happy to switch to Selenium's WebDriver you could create Data Driven tests which could run an iteration for each set of login details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the data driven jar and follow the steps mention here

http://wiki.openqa.org/display/SEL/datadriven

and from this u can easily read yours user name and password from xml

Comment: Please give more details. The linked page might dissappear at any time.

Comment: http://wiki.openqa.org/download/attachments/14975018/datadriven_v0.2.zip       http://wiki.openqa.org/download/attachments/379/selenium-goto.zip         http://wiki.openqa.org/download/attachments/283/includeCommand4IDE_1_3.zip download all jar and addd this extension to your selenium and you can read your user name and password from xml there are example test cases also

Comment: i would like to use datadriven testing by .js file .

Answer (score 0):

hi there is no special commands in IDE for Parametrization but you can parametrize using .js file and with a while loop.

Comment: can you please tell me how to create .js file for selenium ide and how i use this file with ide